# Cookie in Tomcat

Tags: session, tomcat, cookies

Sorry... can anybody help me out? I'm a complete neewbiee to tomcat, but I have to set a cookie with the name 'lastlogin' with the actual timestamp as a value.

How am I supposed to do it?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

```
httpServletResponse.addCookie(new Cookie('lastlogin', new Date().toString());
```